# Insert random numbers (between -1 and 1) into multidimensional array

Tags: matlab

I created the following array:

```
array = zeros(64,1,10);
```

I would like to populate the entire array with random numbers with an interval between -1 and 1 with the rand function.

```
max=1
min=-1
array(:,:,:) = ((max-min).*rand(64,1) + min);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use `rand` out of the box for multi-dimensional data?

```
array = rand(64,1,10);
```

Also, don't use [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) and [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) as variable names.  These are actual functions in MATLAB, so you'd be unintentionally shadowing over the functions with your names.

---

Given your edited question, you want to generate values between `-1` to `1` for a 3D array.  `rand` only generates numbers between 0 and 1, so a trick would be to multiply the output of `rand` by 2 and subtract 1.  Therefore:

```
array = 2*rand(64,1,10) - 1;
```

In general, the formula that you wrote above exactly transforms your data so that it fits between `min` and `max`. However, one caveat I will mention is that the data needs to be normalized between `[0,1]` before doing this transformation. Because the output of `rand` already guarantees this, then we have nothing to worry about.

Therefore, if you did:

```
minVal = -1;
maxVal = 1;
array = (maxVal-minVal)*rand(64,1,10) + minVal;
```

you're already achieving the `[-1,1]` restriction that you wanted to begin with. `maxVal - minVal` will become 2 as `1 - (-1) = 2`, and `minVal` will be `-1`, so you'd be subtracting by 1.  As such, the code I had previously equates to what you had in your original post... just that it now works for 3D (or any shape...) arrays!

Comment: @KarlMorrison - Your formula is already achieving the -1,1 thing anyway.

Comment: Elegant answer! Thanks for the min, max advice, had no idea.

Comment: @KarlMorrison - haha no worries :) This is a trick I use all the time as well.  Good luck!

Comment: For the upgraded quality of the post! +1